# Trouble Retrieving Value with jQuery.val() and Modernizr Webshims Lib

Tags: html, firefox, modernizr, polyfills, shim

I am using Modernizr plus [Webshims](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/) to enable me to use the type="number" type for browsers that don't yet support that option.  It works fine, but I'm having trouble accessing the value of the number input field using jQuery [I'll share the code I'm using in a moment].

In Chrome (which doesn't need the polyfill) I can retrieve the value using val().  In Firefox (which does need a polyfill), I can also retrieve the value IF I don't use the webshim polyfill.

However, once I use webshims I can no longer retrieve the value.

Here is the code that I"m using:

Before the  tag I have the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/bp2/wp-content/themes/method/custom/js/modernizr.custom.65840.js">      </script>
<script src="http://localhost/bp2/wp-content/themes/method/custom/js/webshims/polyfiller.js">   </script>
<script>
jQuery.webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('select, input', window.parent.document).change(function() {
    var test = $('#test135').val();
    console.log(test135);
}).trigger('change');
});

</script>
```

And in the content section I added the following:

```
<input id="test" type="number" placeholder="Test2" max="360" min="0" step="30">
```

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be:

```
console.log(test);
```